# Magento 2.4.2 and elasticsearch issue (sort by position)

Tags: category, sorting, elasticsearch

As I have seen, sort by "position" does not work with Elasticsearch (I have no result when I want to see the products in a category).
I would like to disable position sorting on ALL categories (and let just alphabetical order), is it possible to do it with a MySQL request ? (Or can anyone point me in the right direction to do it ?)
Thanks!